# Retrieving File once I have uploaded it

Tags: python, flask, upload

I'm creating a simple flask app in which the user uploads a file.  I have a number of calculations to do on the csv in a different module, but initially, I'm trying to read several of the column names to place in a drop down input on a form.  My question is much more generic.  Once a user uploads a file, how do I actually keep passing that filename to retrieve?  In this instance, i need to pass the filename variable to the SimpleForm() class.  I'm pretty new and from what I'm not able to pass filename through

```
form = SimpleForm(filename)
```

Here is the block of code in which I try to do that.

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            if columns_len(filename):
                title = filename.split('.')[0].title() #creates the title
                form = SimpleForm(filename) # creates the form
                return render_template('analysis.html',title=title, form=form)
            else:
                flash(u'Your CSV has less than three columns.  Please re-upload', 'error')
        else:
            flash(u'Invalid file type.  Please re-upload', 'error')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and here is the SimpleForm class:

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

# creates the simple form
class SimpleForm(Form):
    list_of_files = ['Standard New/Renew/Upsell/Downsell/Churn Analysis', 'Top Ten Customer Accounts','Churn Analysis']
    second_list = ['Analysis by category']
    files = [(x, x) for x in list_of_files]
    # create a list of value/description tuples

    test = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, nrows = 0, header=0)
    second_files = [(x, x) for x in list(test.columns)]
    second_files = [(x, x) for x in second_list]
    acheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=files)
    bcheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=second_files)
    categories = SelectField('Label',choices = files)
```

Also, In general, what is the best way to keep retrieving that 'filename' variable in other functions or modules?

Comment: Store the filename in a database, like you would with any other data.

Comment: Ok, so just create a database, store it there and always reference when I need to?